# configuration issue with npm-watch -- not hearing changes in some cases

Tags: javascript, npm, build, rollup

I am working on a build script that uses rollup along with other tools to build stuff.  Everything works well individully, but npm-watch is being very selective in what it listens to.  I have confiured it to use four different eatches, but only one (watch:js) responds.  Here is a link to the [repo](https://github.com/sean-olson/rollup_build_tool).  Here is the package.json:

```
{
  "name": "es6_rollup_seed",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "an npm build environment that implements rollup.js",
  "main": "index.js",
  "watch": {
    "watch:html": {
      "patterns": [
        "src"
      ],
      "extensions": "html"
    },
    "watch:js": {
      "patterns": [
        "src/js"
      ],
      "extensions": "js"
    },
    "watch:img": {
      "patterns": [
        "src/img"
      ],
      "extensions": "jpg,png,svg,gif"
    },
    "watch:css": {
      "patterns": [
        "src/scss"
      ],
      "extensions": "scss"
    }    
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "npm run test",
    "start": "run-s init:*",
    "init:create-folders": "mkdirp build/js build/css build/img",
    "init:copy-content": "run-s copy-html",
    "init:start": "run-p serve watch:*",
    "serve": "lite-server -c bs-config.json",
    "watch:html": "npm-watch copy-html",
    "watch:js": "npm-watch compile-js",
    "watch:img": "npm-watch copy-images",
    "watch:css": "npm-watch compile-css",
    "copy-html": "cpx src/*.html build",
    "copy-images": "cpx src/img/*.* build/img",
    "compile-js": "rollup -c",
    "compile-css": "node-sass --output-style expanded --source-map true src/scss/app.scss --output build/css"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/sean-olson/build_environments.git"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "rollup",
    "build",
    "tool",
    "npm"
  ],
  "author": "Sean Olson",
  "license": "MIT",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/sean-olson/build_environments/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/sean-olson/build_environments#readme",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015-rollup": "^3.0.0",
    "cpx": "^1.5.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.3.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.7.2",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.2",
    "npm-watch": "^0.3.0",
    "rollup": "^0.56.5",
    "rollup-plugin-babel": "^3.0.3",
    "rollup-plugin-commonjs": "^9.0.0",
    "rollup-plugin-node-resolve": "^3.2.0",
    "rollup-plugin-replace": "^2.0.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The solution is to use another module, in this case watch-cli